# What are a good set of macros for writing beamer presentations?

Tags: macros, beamer, presentations

I previously asked about tricks for reducing typing when [writing       beamer presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/typing-and-editing-beamer-presentations). I thought it might be useful to write a few macros for common commands.
E.g., something like this:

```
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\begin{block}}
\newcommand{\eb}{\end{block}}
```

I'm always a little wary about defining macros in case it introduces issues.
In particular, I encountered problems when trying to write a macro for `\begin{frame}`.

Has anyone already done this and worked out a good set of macros?

I'd also be interested in whether experienced users think macro redefinition in this case is worth the bother.

Comment: I would advise against having commands that start an environment. It makes it harder to read when environments start and stop if you start obfuscating the `\begin` and `\end` commands.

Comment: If typing is what you are concerned about, I suggest defining keyboard shortcuts/macros in Vim/Emacs/whatever editor you use instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using macros in this way. It does cut down on a bit of typing, but tends to make the source code much more opaque. A better solution is to use an editor that allows you to assign bits of code to shortcuts. For example, I use TeXShop (Mac OSX) and have set the key combination Ctrl+Opt+Cmd+1 to insert the code

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item
\end{enumerate}
```

and place the cursor right after `\item`. This cuts down on typing (I just have to mash down the bottom left of my keyboard and type a number) while still producing a readable source.

I'm sure that there are ways of reproducing this functionality with other editors and on other operating systems as well; [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/typing-and-editing-beamer-presentations/1275#1275) to a very similar question suggests the AutoHotkey utility for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your thoughts and the number of up votes, I think I'll just avoid the macro redefinition.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs+AucTeX already has built in keyboard shortcuts for adding environments, sections and so on (with labels added automatically if needed). A similar approach can be achieved in any other text editor with a flexible enough keyboard shortcut defining structure. This is, as has already been pointed out, preferable to TeX macros for new environments.

One beamer specific macro that I use is the following:

```
\newenvironment{bitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize}}
```

What this does is define a `bitemize` environment that has consecutive items appear one by one on the slides. This doesn't really save all that many keystrokes, but `[<+->]` is tricky to type in a hurry, and since I use Emacs' `C-c C-e` to add environments, it saves me navigating back to the top of the itemize environment to add it.

One could also do the following for a similar small saving when using alert:

```
\newcommand{\balert}[1]{\alert<+->{#1}}
```

I expect this will reveal consecutive `alert`s on consecutive slides. (I haven't used this, I just thought of it now. I don't tend to use alert, but I know people who do.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way of reducing typing by keyboard shortcuts in Linux is the small, very cool editor **Scribes** ( http://scribes.sourceforge.net/ ), where you can import and export your shortcuts as xml. An example of latex shortcuts is at the download site.

For Beamer, I created my own and simply type:

- fr for the whole frame environment or
- bl for a block,
- de for a description,
- item for an itemize environment.

That works very well and is really fast.